# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. Getting object of objects instead of array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I am pretty new to React and I am trying to get data from my Jobly backend. In my code I set company to be the data received from my backend, and company.jobs is seen as an array of objects. However when I try to set jobs to the mapped company.jobs array, it becomes an object of objects instead, causing the error. From my understanding, company.jobs.map() should return an array of data, not an object?

This is the code extracting the data and setting jobs:

```
let [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

const company = await JoblyApi.getCompany(handle);

    
setJobs(jobs = company.jobs.map(j => (
        <JobCard key={j.id}
            title={j.title}
            salary={j.salary}
            equity={j.equity}/>
    )));
```

The data JoblyApi.getCompany(handle) returns is:

```
{
  "company": {
    "handle": "anderson-arias-morrow",
    "name": "Anderson, Arias and Morrow",
    "description": "Somebody program how I. Face give away discussion view act inside. Your official relationship administration here.",
    "numEmployees": 245,
    "logoUrl": "/logos/logo3.png",
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Technical brewer",
        "salary": 157000,
        "equity": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "title": "Embryologist, clinical",
        "salary": 138000,
        "equity": "0"
      },
      ...(more jobs)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here that need some slight tweaking.

1. Your API call is an *effect*, so I would recommend running a `useEffect` hook. Assuming you just need to run it once on initial component render, you can use an empty *dependency array*.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // API call here
}, []);
```

Note that if your effect depends on any variables (e.g., if you want it to run every time `handle` updates), you can provide that in the dependency array. The following effect will run on initial render and every time `handle` changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // API call here
}, [handle]);
```

2. You likely don't want to set your state to the array of `JobCard` components, but rather just your returned data. You can return actual JSX later in the `return` of the entire component.

Your final component code might look something like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  let [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getJobs() {
      const company = await JoblyApi.getCompany(handle);
      setJobs(company.jobs);
    }
    getJobs();
  }, []);

  return jobs.map((j) => (
    <JobCard key={j.id} title={j.title} salary={j.salary} equity={j.equity} />
  ));
}
```

Comment: I refactored my code but unfortunately I am getting the same errors, I am pretty sure the error has something to do with company.jobs. It returns an array of objects in insomnia, however when I console.log(company.jobs) it logs an object of objects. Not sure why it is doing this though

Answer (score 0):

The way you're setting the state is slightly wrong. Your state line should be:

```
setJobs(company.jobs.map(j => (
```

Without the `jobs =`  part.